# MIT's App Inventor can't receive phone calls or show the calling number ... Is it possible?

Tags: android, app-inventor

It's possible to do many things in MIT's app inventor, yet, there is no clear way on how to receive a phone-call/SMS or even showing the calling number ... is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't receive a phone call with App Inventor, there is the [PhoneCall](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/social.html#PhoneCall) component, but you can only `Use this component to dial the phone and make a call.` 
There is the [Texting](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/social.html#Texting) component, which can send and receive SMS and also display the sending phone number: `When a message arrives, the MessageReceived event is raised and provides the sending number and message.`

[image]
Please see the [reference documentation](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/social.html#Texting) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/social.html:

> PhoneCallStarted(number status, text phoneNumber)
>       Event indicating that a phonecall has started. If status is 1, incoming call is ringing; if status is 2, outgoing call is dialled.
>   phoneNumber is the incoming/outgoing phone number. Using this block
>   will add dangerous permissions that will require additional approval
>   if your app is submitted to the Google Play Store.